# When creating and loading a "savedInstanceState", why is it necessary to use constants for the keys?

Tags: android

Looking through this tutorial: http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/04/android-user-interface/

The app assigns a string constant for each value to be saved. Then when the savedinstancestate is made, the values are assigned to the keys. And when the savedinstancestate is loaded, they are found using the keys. Why is it necessary to use the constants as the keys? What's wrong with just using s a string as the key like this?

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putDouble("TOTAL_BILL", finalBill);
    outState.putDouble("CURRENT_TIP", tipAmount);
    outState.putDouble("BILL_WITHOUT_TIP", billBeforeTip);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to use constants if you dont want to, its just a convenience method to not make coding mistakes. Actually with time you will find that you are using a lot of bundles, sharedpreferences and other components requiring use of some string keys. In case of savedinstance handling in activities they are used in single class, but sharedpreferences or using bundles with startActivityForResult thats not the case, such string key constant is used by different classes, sometimes in different packages. Its good practice to manage such constants in some ordered manner. For shared preferences I use separate class called Consts, for startActivityForResult bundle arguments I try to keep keys in Activity beeing called (because it can be called by different activities).

also it makes it easier to prefix such constants with some well know word, ie.: KEY_ , in provided tutorial I would use rather names as KEY_TOTAL_BILL, KEY_CURRENT_TIP, ... This makes it easier to find them using code completion, especially when you have lots of other such fields in class.

Answer (score 1):

If you mistype the key, it could be difficult to find where the error lies. It is much safer to use a constant.

Same goes for storing and retrieving data inside an `Intent`, you wouldn't want to go through every activity that handles that `Intent` looking for a mistyped key.